# Python. Read QDateTime from file with QDataStream

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a binary file created with `QDataStream`.

QDataStream has functions to read int, float, QString, etc. But I don't find the function to read `QDatatime`

My file includes `QDatatime`. But I don't find the function to read `QDatatime`
How can I read the `QDatatime` with Python?

Example:

```
  infile = QtCore.QFile(filepath)
  stream = QtCore.QDataStream(infile)
  header = stream.readQString()
  version = stream.readInt()
  date = stream.read??????
```

Comment: [QDateTime >> operator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#operator-gt-gt): e.g. `dt = QDateTime(); stream >> dt`.

Answer (score 0):

This code works. Thanks to [ekhumoro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984421/ekhumoro)

```
 from PyQt5 import QtCore

 infile = QtCore.QFile(filepath)
 if not infile.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly):
    raise IOError(infile.errorString())
 stream = QtCore.QDataStream(infile)
 header = stream.readQString()
 version = stream.readInt()
 date = QtCore.QDateTime()
 stream >> date
 height = stream.readFloat()
```